# Python application to create Google Map image

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, django, google-maps

I have written a Django app that would get some input and give you an image as output.  The output image has 3 layers:

- Google Map image
- rosreestr (russian docs layer)
- data from geojson layer

I hear that I write code like a junior developer, so please help me improve, especially regarding clear code and architecture.  (I am also interested in learning Erlang or Scala.)

[Full code on GitHub](https://github.com/candyboober/printmap/tree/0180fd14d1628dc59e5f1865fbe56f0e90eb86ae)

**concat.py**

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

import PIL


def concat_images(image, layer, rosreestr=None):
    """
    function that concat png images like sandwich
    used for concat google map static image and
        mapnik layers image
    image - png image google map
    layer - png mapnik image
    """
    buf = StringIO()
    if rosreestr:
        rosreestr = rosreestr.resize(image.size)
        image = PIL.Image.alpha_composite(image, rosreestr)
    PIL.Image.alpha_composite(image, layer).save(buf, 'PNG')
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf
```

**consts.py**

```
from pyproj import Proj
from math import pi


EARTH_RADIUS = 6378137
EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE = 2 * pi * EARTH_RADIUS
INITIAL_RESOLUTION = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 256.0
ORIGIN_SHIFT = EQUATOR_CIRCUMFERENCE / 2.0

MAP_SRS = '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 '
MAP_SRS += '+lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 '
MAP_SRS += '+units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs'

EPSG4326 = 'epsg:4326'
EPSG3857 = 'epsg:3857'
IN_PROJ = Proj(init=EPSG4326)
OUT_PROJ = Proj(init=EPSG3857)

TMP_DIR = 'tmp'
TMP_GEOJSON = 'tmp.geojson'
```

exceptions.py

```
class GeometryTypeError(Exception):
    pass
```

map_filler.py

```
import mapnik
from mapnik._mapnik import DataGeometryType
from pyproj import transform
import PIL

import os
import json
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

from . import utils
from . import consts
from .exceptions import GeometryTypeError


def create_symbolizer(datasource):
    """
    symbolizer fabric for various types of shape
    """
    geom_type = datasource.geometry_type()
    if geom_type == DataGeometryType.Point:
        symbolizer = mapnik.PointSymbolizer()
    elif geom_type == DataGeometryType.Polygon:
        symbolizer = mapnik.PolygonSymbolizer()
    elif geom_type == DataGeometryType.LineString:
        symbolizer = mapnik.LineSymbolizer()
    elif geom_type == DataGeometryType.Collection:
        symbolizer = mapnik.LineSymbolizer()
    else:
        msg = 'Invalid geomerty type of object %s' % datasource
        raise GeometryTypeError(msg)
    return symbolizer


class MapFiller(mapnik.Map):
    """
    mapnik.Map object that create map with included styles,
        datasource, coordinates
    """
    styles = {'stroke': 'color',
              'fill': 'color',
              'fill_opacity': 'opacity',
              'stroke_opacity': 'opacity',
              'opacity': 'opacity',
              'stroke_width': 'weight',
              'width': 'weight'}
    def __init__(self, imager, **kwargs):
        self.upperleft = imager.upperleft
        self.lowerright = imager.lowerright
        box_xy = self.create_valid_box(imager)
        super(MapFiller, self).__init__(*box_xy, **kwargs)
        self.srs = consts.MAP_SRS

        if not os.path.isdir(consts.TMP_DIR):
            os.mkdir(consts.TMP_DIR)

    def create_valid_box(self, imager):
        self.dx = int(imager.dx)
        self.dy = int(imager.dy)
        return (self.dx, self.dy)

    def filling_map(self, layers):
        for i in range(len(layers)):
            self.append_layer(layers[i], i)

    def append_layer(self, layer, i):
        self.correct_layer_geom(layer)

        geom = layer.get('geom')
        if not geom:
            return
        layer_geojson = self.create_geojson(geom)

        filename = os.path.join(consts.TMP_DIR, consts.TMP_GEOJSON)
        datasource = self.write_datasource(filename, layer_geojson)
        symbolizer = create_symbolizer(datasource)
        self.set_style(symbolizer, layer['style'])

        name = 'style%s' % str(i)
        self.push_style(name, symbolizer)
        self.push_layer(name, datasource)

    def correct_layer_geom(self, layer):
        for j in range(len(layer.get('geom', []))):
            if layer['geom'][j]:
                layer['geom'][j]['coordinates'] = \
                    self.epsg4326_to_3857(layer['geom'][j])

    def create_geojson(self, geom):
        geojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection"}
        geojson['features'] = [{"type": "Feature",
                                        "geometry": coord,
                                        "properties": {}} for coord in geom]
        return geojson

    def write_datasource(self, filename, geojson):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(geojson))
        datasource = mapnik.Datasource(type='geojson', file=filename)
        os.remove(filename)
        return datasource

    def push_layer(self, name, datasource):
        new_layer = mapnik.Layer(name)
        new_layer.datasource = datasource
        new_layer.srs = consts.MAP_SRS
        new_layer.styles.append(name)
        self.layers.append(new_layer)

    def push_style(self, name, symbolizer):
        style = mapnik.Style()
        rule = mapnik.Rule()
        rule.symbols.append(symbolizer)
        style.rules.append(rule)
        self.append_style(name, style)

    def epsg4326_to_3857(self, coordinates):
        if coordinates['type'] == 'Point':
            return self.transform_point(coordinates['coordinates'])

        elif coordinates['type'] == 'MultiLineString' or \
                coordinates['type'] == 'Polygon':
                return self.list_comp_map(coordinates['coordinates'])

        elif coordinates['type'] == 'LineString' or \
                coordinates['type'] == 'MultiPoint':
                coords = coordinates['coordinates']
                return [self.transform_point(p) for p in coords]

        elif coordinates['type'] == 'MultiPolygon':
            return map(lambda cc: self.list_comp_map(cc),
                       coordinates['coordinates'])

        else:
            msg = 'Invalid geomerty type of json object by database'
            raise GeometryTypeError(msg)

    def set_style(self, sym, params):
        for k, v in self.styles.iteritems():
            if hasattr(sym, k) and v in params:
                if v == 'color':
                    setattr(sym, k, mapnik.Color(str(params[v])))
                else:
                    setattr(sym, k, float(params[v]))
        return sym

    def render_map(self):
        self.map_tmp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
        mapnik.render_to_file(self,
                              self.map_tmp_file.name,
                              'png')

    def zoom_to_layers_box(self):
        box = self.create_box(self.upperleft, self.lowerright)
        self.zoom_to_box(box)

    def create_box(self, upperleft, lowerright):
        upperleft, lowerright = utils.get_coords(upperleft, lowerright, False)
        upperleft = MapFiller.transform_point(upperleft)
        lowerright = MapFiller.transform_point(lowerright)
        coords = upperleft + lowerright
        return mapnik.Box2d(*coords)

    @staticmethod
    def transform_point(coords):
        return list(transform(consts.IN_PROJ,
                              consts.OUT_PROJ,
                              *coords))

    def list_comp_map(self, list_of_points):
        return map(lambda c: [self.transform_point(p) for p in c],
                   list_of_points)
```

**map_imager.py**

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from math import ceil
import urllib

from PIL import Image

from . import utils


class BaseMapImager(object):
    zoom = None
    upperleft = None
    lowerright = None
    maxsize = 450
    scale = 1
    bottom = 0
    encoded_delimeter = '%2C'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unpack_kwargs(**kwargs)
        self.valid_params()
        self.set_coords_angles_of_image()

    def valid_params(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'upperleft') or not hasattr(self, 'lowerright'):
            raise Exception('Not enough params, need lowerright and upperleft')

    def unpack_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

    def init_image(self):
        self.create_parent_image()
        self.fill_image()
        return self.parent_image

    def create_parent_image(self):
        size = (int(self.dx), int(self.dy))
        self.parent_image = Image.new("RGBA", size)

    def load_image(self, url):
        f = urllib.urlopen(url)
        return Image.open(StringIO(f.read()))

    def fill_image(self):
        for x in range(self.cols):
            for y in range(self.rows):
                self.fill_in_position(x, y)

    def set_coords_angles_of_image(self):
        ullat, ullon = map(float, self.upperleft.split(','))
        lrlat, lrlon = map(float, self.lowerright.split(','))
        self.coords = {'upperleft_lat': ullat,
                       'upperleft_lon': ullon,
                       'lowerright_lat': lrlat,
                       'lowerright_lon': lrlon}


class MapImager(BaseMapImager):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MapImager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_size_of_image()
        self.get_cols_rows()
        self.set_sizes_of_chunk(self.bottom)

    def set_size_of_image(self):
        coords = self.coords
        upperleft_x_y = utils.latlontopixels(coords['upperleft_lat'],
                                             coords['upperleft_lon'],
                                             self.zoom)
        self.upperleft_x, self.upperleft_y = upperleft_x_y
        lowerright_x_y = utils.latlontopixels(coords['lowerright_lat'],
                                              coords['lowerright_lon'],
                                              self.zoom)
        self.lowerright_x, self.lowerright_y = lowerright_x_y
        self.dx = self.lowerright_x - self.upperleft_x
        self.dy = self.upperleft_y - self.lowerright_y

    def get_cols_rows(self):
        self.cols = int(ceil(self.dx / self.maxsize))
        self.rows = int(ceil(self.dy / self.maxsize))

    def set_sizes_of_chunk(self, bottom):
        self.largura = int(ceil(self.dx / self.cols))
        self.altura = int(ceil(self.dy / self.rows))
        self.alturaplus = self.altura + bottom

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        dxn = self.largura * (0.5 + x)
        dyn = self.altura * (0.5 + y)
        px = self.upperleft_x + dxn
        py = self.upperleft_y - dyn - self.bottom / 2
        latn, lonn = utils.pixelstolatlon(px, py, self.zoom)
        return self.latn_lonn_to_string(latn, lonn)

    def latn_lonn_to_string(self, latn, lonn):
        return ','.join((str(latn), str(lonn)))

    def fill_in_position(self, x, y):
        position = self.set_position(x, y)
        urlparams = self.get_url_params(position)
        url = self.url + urlparams
        image_inst = self.load_image(url)
        self.parent_image.paste(image_inst,
                                (int(x * self.largura),
                                 int(y * self.altura)))


class GoogleImager(MapImager):
    """
    interprate for google
    """

    url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?'
    maxsize = 640

    def get_url_params(self, position):
        url = urllib.urlencode({'center': position,
                                'zoom': str(self.zoom),
                                'size': '%dx%d' % (self.largura,
                                                   self.alturaplus),
                                'maptype': self.map_type,
                                'scale': self.scale})
        return url.replace(self.encoded_delimeter, ',')


class YandexImager(MapImager):
    url = 'https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?'
    maxsize = 450

    # def load_image(url):
    #     return urllib.urlopen(url)

    def latn_lonn_to_string(self, latn, lonn):
        return ','.join((str(lonn), str(latn)))

    def get_url_params(self, position):
        url = urllib.urlencode({'ll': position,
                                'z': str(self.zoom),
                                'size': '%d,%d' % (self.largura,
                                                   self.alturaplus),
                                'l': self.map_type,
                                'scale': self.scale})
        return url.replace(self.encoded_delimeter, ',')


class GoogleMapImager(GoogleImager):
    map_type = 'roadmap'


class GoogleSatImager(GoogleImager):
    map_type = 'satellite'


class YandexMapImager(YandexImager):
    map_type = 'map'


class YandexSatImager(YandexMapImager):
    map_type = 'sat'


class TwoGisMapImager(MapImager):
    url = 'http://static.maps.2gis.com/1.0?'
    maxsize = 1200

    def latn_lonn_to_string(self, latn, lonn):
        return ','.join((str(lonn), str(latn)))

    def get_url_params(self, position):
        url = urllib.urlencode({'center': position,
                                'zoom': str(self.zoom),
                                'size': '%d,%d' % (self.largura,
                                                   self.alturaplus)})
        return url.replace(self.encoded_delimeter, ',')


class OSMMapImager(MapImager):
    access_token = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGVubnk1MzEiLCJhIjoiY2l3NHhlbjkwMDAwcTJ0bzRzc3p0bmNxaCJ9.QG39g1_q4GANnTPVIizKEg'
    url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.emerald/'
    maxsize = 1280

    def latn_lonn_to_string(self, latn, lonn):
        return ','.join((str(lonn), str(latn)))

    def get_url_params(self, position):
        url = '%s,%s/%sx%s.png?' % (position,
                                    self.zoom,
                                    self.largura,
                                    self.altura)
        url += urllib.urlencode({'access_token': self.access_token})
        return url.replace(self.encoded_delimeter, ',')


class RosreestrImager(MapImager):
    maxsize = 2048
    url = 'http://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/Cadastre/MapServer/export?'
    layers = 'show:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24'
    bboxSR = 4326
    imageSR = 3857
    size = '2048,2048'
    format = 'png24'
    transparent = True
    f = 'image'
    dpi = 15
    bbox = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RosreestrImager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.calculate_numbers_of_chunks()
        self.calculate_delta_coords_image()

    def calculate_delta_coords_image(self):
        self.calculate_delta_lon()
        self.calculate_delta_lat()

    def calculate_delta_lon(self):
        lowerright = self.coords['lowerright_lon']
        upperleft = self.coords['upperleft_lon']
        self.delta_lon = abs(upperleft - lowerright) / \
            self.number_of_chunks

    def calculate_delta_lat(self):
        lowerright = self.coords['lowerright_lat']
        upperleft = self.coords['upperleft_lat']
        self.delta_lat = abs(upperleft - lowerright) / \
            self.number_of_chunks

    def latn_lonn_to_string(self, latn, lonn):
        return ','.join((str(lonn), str(latn)))

    def get_image_size(self):
        return '%s,%s' % (self.maxsize, self.maxsize)

    def calculate_numbers_of_chunks(self):
        self.number_of_chunks = self.detail_level + 1

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        ullon = self.coords['upperleft_lon'] + self.delta_lon * x
        lrlon = ullon + self.delta_lon * (x + 1)
        ullat = self.coords['upperleft_lat'] + self.delta_lon * y
        lrlat = ullat + self.delta_lat * (y + 1)
        return '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (ullon, ullat, lrlon, lrlat)

    def get_url_params(self, position):
        url = urllib.urlencode({'layers': self.layers,
                                'bboxSR': self.bboxSR,
                                'imageSR': self.imageSR,
                                'size': self.get_image_size(),
                                'format': self.format,
                                'transparent': self.transparent,
                                'f': self.f,
                                'dpi': self.dpi,
                                'bbox': position})
        return url.replace(self.encoded_delimeter, ',')


def select_map_image(name):
    map_hash = {'google_map': GoogleMapImager,
                'google_sat': GoogleSatImager,
                'yandex_map': YandexMapImager,
                'yandex_sat': YandexSatImager,
                '2gis': TwoGisMapImager,
                'osm': OSMMapImager}
    return map_hash[name]

def create_map_image(map_lay):
    map_lay.render_map()
    return PIL.Image.open(map_lay.map_tmp_file.name)
```

**rosreestr.py**

```
import urllib

from PIL import Image

from .map_imager import BaseMapImager


class RosreestrImager(BaseMapImager):
    # longitude binded to x coordinates
    # latitude to y
    maxsize = 2048
    url = 'http://pkk5.rosreestr.ru/arcgis/rest/services/Cadastre/Cadastre/MapServer/export?'
    layers = 'show:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24'
    bboxSR = 4326
    imageSR = 3857
    size = '2048,2048'
    format = 'png24'
    transparent = True
    f = 'image'
    dpi = 15
    bbox = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RosreestrImager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.normalize_angles()
        self.calculate_bbox()
        self.calculate_numbers_of_chunks()
        self.calculate_delta_coords_image()
        self.create_parent_image()

    def normalize_angles(self):
        self.normalize_angle('lowerright')
        self.normalize_angle('upperleft')

    def normalize_angle(self, name):
        angle_attr = getattr(self, name)
        tmp = angle_attr.split(',')
        tmp.reverse()
        setattr(self, name, ','.join(tmp))

    def calculate_bbox(self):
        self.bbox = self.upperleft + ',' + self.lowerright

    def calculate_numbers_of_chunks(self):
        self.number_of_chunks = self.detail_level + 1

    def calculate_delta_coords_image(self):
        self.calculate_delta_lon()
        self.calculate_delta_lat()

    def calculate_delta_lon(self):
        lowerright = self.coords['lowerright_lon']
        upperleft = self.coords['upperleft_lon']
        self.delta_lon = abs(upperleft - lowerright) / \
            self.number_of_chunks

    def calculate_delta_lat(self):
        lowerright = self.coords['lowerright_lat']
        upperleft = self.coords['upperleft_lat']
        self.delta_lat = abs(upperleft - lowerright) / \
            self.number_of_chunks

    def create_parent_image(self):
        self.parent_image = Image.new("RGBA")

    def create_image(self):
        for x in xrange(1, self.number_of_chunks + 1):
            for y in xrange(1, self.number_of_chunks + 1):
                self.create_chunk_image(x, y)

    def create_chunk_image(self, x, y):
        bbox = self.calculate_bbox_chunk(x, y)
        urlparams = self.get_url_params(bbox)
        url = self.url + urlparams
        img = self.load_image(url)

    def calculate_bbox_chunk(self, x, y):
        ullon = self.coords['upperleft_lon']
        lrlon = ullon + self.delta_lon * x
        ullat = self.coords['upperleft_lat']
        lrlat = ullat + self.delta_lat * y
        return '%s,%s,%s,%s' % (ullon, ullat, lrlon, lrlat)

    def init_image(self):
        urlparams = self.get_url_params()
        url = self.url + urlparams
        return self.load_image(url)

    def get_url_params(self, bbox=None):
        url = urllib.urlencode({'layers': self.layers,
                                'bboxSR': self.bboxSR,
                                'imageSR': self.imageSR,
                                'size': self.get_image_size(),
                                'format': self.format,
                                'transparent': self.transparent,
                                'f': self.f,
                                'dpi': self.dpi,
                                'bbox': bbox or self.bbox})
        return url.replace(self.encoded_delimeter, ',')

    def get_image_size(self):
        return '%s,%s' % (self.maxsize, self.maxsize)
```

**utils.py**

```
from math import pi, log, tan, atan, exp
import urllib2
import json

from . import consts
from .exceptions import GeometryTypeError


def latlontopixels(lat, lon, zoom):
    mx = (lon * consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT) / 180.0
    my = log(tan((90 + lat) * pi / 360.0)) / (pi / 180.0)
    my = (my * consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT) / 180.0
    res = consts.INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    px = (mx + consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    py = (my + consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT) / res
    return px, py


def pixelstolatlon(px, py, zoom):
    """
    convert resolution of image to coordinates
    """
    res = consts.INITIAL_RESOLUTION / (2**zoom)
    mx = px * res - consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT
    my = py * res - consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT
    lat = (my / consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    lat = 180 / pi * (2 * atan(exp(lat * pi / 180.0)) - pi / 2.0)
    lon = (mx / consts.ORIGIN_SHIFT) * 180.0
    return lat, lon


def get_coords(upperleft, lowerright, concat=True):
    """
    convert bounds coordinates strings to array of coordinates
    """
    upperleft = coords_string_to_float(upperleft, reverse=True)
    # upperleft = coords_string_to_float(upperleft)
    lowerright = coords_string_to_float(lowerright, reverse=True)
    if concat:
        return upperleft + lowerright
    else:
        return upperleft, lowerright


def coords_string_to_float(coord, reverse=False):
    """
    string coordiantes to float
    """
    values = coord.split(',')
    result = [float(v) for v in values]
    if reverse:
        result.reverse()
    return result


def map_geom_data(obj):
    """
    from url and styles hash
    create object that include
    geomatry of object and styles
    """
    response = urllib2.urlopen(obj['url']).read()
    response = json.loads(response)
    layer = {}
    if 'features' in response:
        layer['geom'] = [geom['geometry'] for geom in response['features']]
    else:
        msg = 'Invalid geojson'
        raise GeometryTypeError(msg)
    if 'style' in obj:
        layer['style'] = obj['style']
    else:
        layer['style'] = {}
    return layer
```

**views.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

import json

from .map_imager import select_map_image, create_map_image, RosreestrImager
from .map_filler import MapFiller
from . import utils
from .concat import concat_images
from .mixins import respond_as_attachment


class PrintLayView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.init_data(request)
        if self.include_rosreestr:
            self.create_rosreestr_image()
        try:
            self.create_map_image()
        except IOError:
            return HttpResponse('Произошла ошибка. Попробуй задать меньше "Максимальный размер плитки (тайла)"')
        self.create_lay_image()
        image_stream = concat_images(self.img, self.lay, self.img_rosreestr)
        return respond_as_attachment(request, image_stream)

    def init_data(self, request):
        self.img_rosreestr = None
        self.data = json.loads(request.GET['data'])
        self.valid_data()
        self.unpack_data()

    def valid_data(self):
        if 'layersProps' not in self.data:
            return HttpResponse('Data is not a valid, need `layersProps`')
        if 'mapName' not in self.data:
            return HttpResponse('Data is not a valid, need `mapName`')

    def unpack_data(self):
        self.layers_props = json.loads(self.data['layersProps'])
        self.upperleft = self.data['upperleft']
        self.lowerright = self.data['lowerright']
        self.detail_level = int(self.data['detailLevel'])
        self.zoom = int(self.data['zoom'])
        self.zoom += self.detail_level
        self.map_name = self.data['mapName']
        self.include_rosreestr = self.data['includeRosreestr']

    def create_rosreestr_image(self):
        rosreestr_imager = RosreestrImager(upperleft=self.upperleft,
                                           lowerright=self.lowerright,
                                           detail_level=self.detail_level,
                                           zoom=self.zoom)
        self.img_rosreestr = rosreestr_imager.init_image()

    def create_map_image(self):
        map_imager = select_map_image(self.map_name)
        self.imager = map_imager(upperleft=self.upperleft,
                                 lowerright=self.lowerright,
                                 zoom=self.zoom)
        self.img = self.imager.init_image()

    def create_lay_image(self):
        layers = map(utils.map_geom_data,
                     self.layers_props)

        Map = MapFiller(self.imager)
        Map.filling_map(layers)
        Map.zoom_to_layers_box()
        self.lay = create_map_image(Map)
```

**mixins.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

import mimetypes
import os
import urllib
import uuid


def respond_as_attachment(request, file_stream):
    """
    mixin that return file like stream
    """
    original_filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.png'
    response = HttpResponse(file_stream.read())
    file_stream.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    response['Content-Length'] = file_stream.tell()
    file_stream.close()
    type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(original_filename)
    if type is None:
        type = 'application/octet-stream'
    response['Content-Type'] = type
    if encoding is not None:
        response['Content-Encoding'] = encoding

    if 'WebKit' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
        filename_header = 'filename=%s' % original_filename.encode('utf-8')
    elif 'MSIE' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
        filename_header = ''
    else:
        encoded_name = original_filename.encode('utf-8')
        filename_header = \
            'filename*=UTF-8\'\'%s' % urllib.quote(encoded_name)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; ' + filename_header
    return response
```

Comment: if you have this type of thing going on in your code if type == square then do this elseif type ==circle then do that, if you are checking for types and then responding - that's a no-no in OOP. it means you are missing a duck type.

Comment: here this may help: https://bkspurgeon.github.io/BKSpurgeon.github.io/duck-types/

Comment: Thanks you, but I can't  inherite from this geometry type classes, I may just appropriate lambda function for for every of this type, but I think ii's not a better idea. Or not?

Comment: here is another option: https://gist.github.com/BKSpurgeon/8d32e295278236f439cbe80ac332df6e

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BKSpurgeon's duck type criticism of `create_symbolizer()`. (Also, typo in `msg`, with possible copy-n-paste error into `epsg4326_to_3857()`.)

In consts.py MAP_SRS, I see `+a=6378137 +b=6378137`, but was hoping to see `+a=%d +b=%d` with string formatting filling them in from EARTH_RADIUS.

Otherwise, it looks pretty good.